# How to convert a TypeScript import statement into a JS Require statement

Tags: javascript, typescript

How would I convert the follow TS statement

```
import {TNSFontIcon, fonticon} from 'nativescript-fonticon';
```

Into a Javascript require statement? My thought is:

```
TNSFontIcon = require('nativescript-fonticon’).TNSFontIcon()
```

But the TS statement is importing multiple things from the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you can write:

```
var package = require('nativescript-fonticon');

var TNSFontIcon = package.TNSFontIcon;
var fonticon = package.fonticon;

// and later use it as follows
var obj = new TNSFontIcon();
```

This assumes that `nativescript-fonticon` is a [commonjs](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html#exports) package. If you're compiling the `nativescript-fonticon` from TypeScript you can choose from various output formats, see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Note that `require` isn't a standard JavaScript function and you need to polyfill with eg. [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry it is a commonjs package pulled from NPM